# SVDs of the matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, svd

This is from Trefethen's *Numerical Linear Algebra*, lecture 4, exercise 1(d).

> Determine the SVDs of the matrix
> $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$$

---

This matrix maps both $[1, 0]$, $[0, 1]$ to $[1, 0]$, and there is $1$ as a singular value. The corresponding singular vector is $[1, 0]$. Thus the SVD is $AV= U\Sigma$
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}  1 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & ? \\ 0  & ?\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & ?\end{bmatrix} $$

Since the given matrix $A$ doesn't have full rank, I'm having trouble filling in the empty entries so that the $U$ matrix is unitary.

Comment: don't sweat https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=svd+%7B%7B1%2C1%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%7D%7D .

Comment: How does throwing a random Wolfram Alpha link at OP help them to calculate the SVD and understand where it comes from, or otherwise address their concerns? Obviously people can throw half the posts on this site into a calculator of some sort, but that doesn't really help them learn the underlying method.

Comment: some hint perhaps

Comment: One approach starts by noting that the singular values of $A$ are the eigenvalues of $A^T A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a procedure you can use to find the SVD of $A$. It's quite "quick and dirty" in the sense that I've just shown the procedure and not explained anything, but hopefully, it'll help as a guide for when you learn the general procedure from someone much more qualified than I :)

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ with SVD $A=U\Sigma V^T$.

First, find the eigenvalues of $A^TA$. So we have
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}.$$
With eigenvalues $\lambda_1=2,\lambda_2=0$ both with algebraic multiplicity $1$. The singular values of $A$ are therefore $\sigma_1=\sqrt2$ and $\sigma_2=0$.

Next, find the eigenspaces corresponding to each eigenvalue. For $\lambda_1=2$, we have
$$
E_{\lambda_1}=\ker\left(\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1\end{bmatrix}\right)=\mathrm{span}\left\{\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}\right\}.
$$
And for $\lambda_2=0$ we have
$$
E_{\lambda_2}=\ker\left(\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}\right)=\mathrm{span}\left\{\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}\right\}.
$$
Now take the union of the spanning sets for the eigenspaces and make the set orthonormal. The Gram–Schmidt process is the way to go. We obtain$$\left\{\begin{bmatrix} \frac{\sqrt2}{2} \\ \frac{\sqrt2}{2}\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix} -\frac{\sqrt2}{2} \\ \frac{\sqrt2}{2}\end{bmatrix}\right\}.$$ Name these vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$, respectively. Then, define
$$
u_1=\frac{1}{\sigma_1}Av_1=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
We would like the define $u_2$ in the same way $u_2=\frac{1}{\sigma_2}Av_2$, but $\sigma_2=0$, so instead we set $u_2$ to be a matrix orthonormal to $u_1$. Clearly,
$$
u_2=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Finally, we obtain following the matrices:
$$
\begin{align}
V&=\begin{bmatrix} v_1 & v_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} \frac{\sqrt2}{2} &  -\frac{\sqrt2}{2}\\ \frac{\sqrt2}{2} &  \frac{\sqrt2}{2}\end{bmatrix}\\
U&=\begin{bmatrix} u_1 & u_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\\
\Sigma&=\begin{bmatrix} \sigma_1 & 0 \\ 0 & \sigma_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} \sqrt2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}
$$

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}^\top = \sqrt{2} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \end{bmatrix}^\top =: \sigma_1 {\bf u}_1 {\bf v}_1^\top $$

Can you find unit vectors ${\bf u}_2$ and ${\bf v}_2$?  Do you know what the singular value $\sigma_2$ is?